# Get Model type response in web api filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get my modeltype that is returned from the controller's action in the actionfilter.

I tried to look in the actionExecutedContext.Response object but i cannot find anything.

Comment: Can you post any code that you've tried?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class FooFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {
         public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
            var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
            if (objectContent != null) {
                var type = objectContent.ObjectType; //type of the returned object
                var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value
            }

        }
    }
```